# How to get back to Windows 7 after downgrade to XP

Tags: windows-xp, downgrade

I used the CD that came with my old laptop to wipe all data and reinstall Windows.
To my horror, the CD installed Windows XP instead of Windows 7 !!!

How can I get back to Windows 7 ? 
I still have the product key on the laptop.

I would need to boot Windows 7 from a USB because I lost all drivers for the old laptop and it was my only CD burner (not DVD burner).

Comment: If you actually do have a license.  There is a Superuser question with links to safe Windows 7 images.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion you are screwed. I would suggest two similar courses  of action.

Burn a brand new copy of the Windows version you want to use and make  a clean format/install of the above OS. Then you can register with your key if you still feel like doing so.

Another way to go, that works well for me, is to run a Linux distro on a USB drive. This way you are able to plug in an internet cable (since you have no drivers  installed) and then download windows drivers manually and any other MS product you want. Additionally you can use Brasero burner or any  other tool you  are familiar  with  to burn the OS image. Then perform the procedure described above, by installing a clean version  of your preferred OS.

I didn't got your question quite well, so my  answer could be a bit vague or off-topic. Please let me  know  in  case i can still  help you.

Comment: What would booting of Linux serve before a clean install of Windows?

Comment: Well booting Linux from a USB hard drive, usually is easier

Comment: But how could it help to install Windows?

Comment: example: Run Linux, plug in an internet cable and download Windows drivers manually and any other MS product necessary. Burn a copy of windows with Brasero  or any other tool of your choice  and go forth by installing windows on your system (era

Comment: This makes sense! Unfortunately in you reply you suggest using is just to "boot your PC from there". I suggest you extending your reply by what you described in the comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11558/discussion-between-pabouk-and-ldn-5602)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so putting here for posterity the solution to this conundrum.

1. Download the appropriate ISO file, see [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)
2. Create a bootable USB drive, see [YUMI Multiboot](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
3. If you get error **Windows Setup could not configure Windows on this computer’s hardware**, see the solution [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2466753)
4. If you get error **Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition** just make the hardrive the first option in the BIOS boot order.